# Suspend and login loop after installing 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, suspend

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) from Windows 10 using bootable USB, I experienced login loop and the screen turn off (like suspend/sleep) everytime like for every 10 secs. I have to turn it on again. Even while typing on the console (tty), it repeatedly happens. What should I do? Thanks.